# How could i add up the values in each row of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my task

[image]

I have the program, printing out the values in the arrays, that step does not need to be there, that is the last for loop. Instead of that I need add the rows up, value by value using the die class i have, the code is something.getFaceValue();.

Code is Below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ASgn8 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many players? ");
    int playerCount = scan.nextInt(); // get number of participant player...
    scan.nextLine();

    Die[] tempDie = new Die[5]; // temporary purpose
    Die[][] finalDie = new Die[5][]; // final array in which all rolled dies stores...
    int tempVar = 0;

    String [] playerName = new String[playerCount]; // stores player name

    int totalRollDie = 0; // keep track number of user hash rolled dies...

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) // get all player name from command prompt...
    {
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        String plyrName = scan.nextLine();
        playerName[i] = plyrName;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    { 

        System.out.println(playerName[i] + "'s turn....");
            totalRollDie = 0;
            Die d = new Die();
            System.out.println("Rolled : " + d.roll()) ;
            tempDie[totalRollDie] = d; 
            totalRollDie++;
            System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();

                while(choice == 1)
                {
                    if(totalRollDie < 5)
                    {
                    Die dd = new Die();
                    System.out.println("Rolled : " + dd.roll()) ; 
                    tempDie[totalRollDie] = dd;
                    totalRollDie++;
                    System.out.println("Want More (Yes/No) ???");
                    choice = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }

            finalDie[i] = new Die[totalRollDie];
            for(int var = 0 ; var < totalRollDie ; var++)
            {
                finalDie[i][var] = tempDie[var]; 
            }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ;i < playerCount ; i++) //prints out the values stored in the array. need to sum them instead.
    { 
        System.out.println(" --------- " + playerName[i] + " ------------ ");

        for(Die de : finalDie[i])
        {
            System.out.println(de);
        }
    }


    tempDie = null;

}
}
```

Anyone have any tips?

EDIT: Die class

```
public class Die
{
   private final int MAX = 6;  

   private int faceValue;  


   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }


   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   public void setFaceValue(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }


   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

     return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your Die class?

Comment: Edited it in to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append following code into your existance code,

```
public static void main(String... s)
{
......

int score[][] = new int[playerCount][2];

        for(int i = 0 ;i < playerCount ; i++){ // finally print whatever user's roll value with all try...
        //  System.out.println(" --------- " + playerName[i] + " ------------ ");
            int playerTotalScore = 0;
            for(Die de : finalDie[i]){
            //  System.out.println(de);
                playerTotalScore += de.getFaceValue();
            }
            score[i][0] = i;
            score[i][1]=playerTotalScore;
        }

        tempDie = null;

        System.out.println("------------- Participant Score Card -------------");
        System.out.println("Index    PlayerName    Score");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < score.length ; i++){
            System.out.println(score[i][0] + "       -       " + playerName[score[i][0]] + "       -       "  + score[i][1]);
        }

        int temp[][] = new int[1][2];
        for(int i = 0 ; i< score.length; i++){
            for(int j = i+1 ; j<score.length;j++){
                if(score[i][1] < score[j][1]){
                    temp[0][0] = score[i][0];
                    temp[0][1] = score[i][1];
                    score[i][0] = score[j][0];
                    score[i][1] = score[j][1];
                     score[j][0] = temp[0][0];
                     score[j][1] = temp[0][1];
                    }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-----------------WINNER---------------------");
            System.out.println(score[0][0] + " - " + playerName[score[0][0]] + " - " + score[0][1]);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");

} // end of main method...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you could store the value in a variable;

```
int[] mPlayerScores = new int[playerCount];
String name = "";

for(int i = 0 ;i < playerCount ; i++) //prints out the values stored in the array. need to sum them instead.
{ 

    int playerScoreSum = 0;
    name = playerName[i];
    System.out.println(" --------- " + name + " ------------ ");

    for(Die de : finalDie[i])
    {
        playerScoreSum += de;

    }

 // this should store the sums in an array
 mPlayerScores[i] = playerScoreSum;

 //display the result for each player outside the for-loop to avoid continous printing
 System.out.println(playerScoreSum);

}

    //finds the highest score
    double max = mPlayerScores[0];

    for (int j = 1; j< mPlayerScores.length; j++)
    {
     if (mPlayerScores[j] > max)
     {
      max = mPlayerScores[j];

     }
    }
 System.out.println(name+" is the winner with " + max+ " score");
```

Comment: That works for one player, however i need it stored for two or more players, so i can compare them.